# Can I print on a Linux local printer using a remote windows driver?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, printing, cups

I have 10 Raspberry Pi's (RPI) all of which have their own USB Zebra GK420d label printer. After installing CUPS to each of them I can print labels to their printer using EPL2 PPD but it is too slow, especially for PDFs. Only two variants of print jobs get printed: PDFs from Evince, and generated web pages from Chromium.

When printing PDFs on a RPI through CUPS the filter process is pdftopdf -> gstoraster -> rastertolabel, which takes too long to print. Can this be sped up? Can I send a job from a Linux machine to a Windows machine which will then send 'the same job' to the same Linux machines printer to print, using the Windows driver? Or am I simply overlooking something?

EDIT: I haven't got an answer for my own question but my alternate solution was to write my own ZPL, still printing through cups but as a raw queue (no filters used)